# How can I show JSON formatting only for one content type and keep the default for all others?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm working in a SharePoint library that contains both file and folder-type items.

I'm trying to replace the standard formatting for folders in a Name column with a clickable standard hyperlink. (The intention is to allow users can middle-click to open folders in a new window.)

I can cause the whole link to disappear if the content type matches my custom folder content type.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "='AllItems.aspx?id=' + @currentField"
  },
  "style": {
    "visibility": "=if([$ContentTypeId]=='0x***mycontenttypeid***','visible', 'hidden')"
  }
}
```

However, this breaks navigation for file items on two counts:

- file links simply don't appear
- even if they did, the link in the `href` attribute would not work for a file item

What I'd like is to fallback to the default formatting for non-folder types. Is this possible? If not, will I have to construct a URL to display files, and how? (The `defaultClick` action only seems to work on `button`, not `a` elements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSON code similar to this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "attributes": {
        "href": "='AllItems.aspx?id=' + @currentField"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if([$ContentType]=='Folder','block', 'none')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "customRowAction": {
        "action": "defaultClick"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if([$ContentType]=='Folder','none', 'block')"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can apply conditions based on either `[$ContentType]` or `[$ContentTypeId]` as per your convenience.

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: Perfect, thanks - I hadn't realised it was possible to apply the `defaultClick` action to a `div`, not just a `button`.

Comment: For me `[$ContentType]` is empty, `[$ContentTypeId]` is not, why? I had to do `"display": "=if(substring([$ContentTypeId], 0,5)=='0x012','none', 'block')"`

Comment: You have to show/include content type in documet library view in order to refer it's value in JSON formatting.